# Compose services with named volume not working with Windows containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-container

I'm trying to created a named volume in which I can expose files from one Windows container to another.

The following **docker-compose.yml** produces an error 'The request is not supported':

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  nano:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809
    volumes:
      - test-data:C:/test-data
volumes:
  test-data:
    name: test-data
```

```
[+] Running 2/3
 - Network test_default   Created                                                                                                 0.8s 
 - Volume "test-data"     Created                                                                                                 0.0s 
 - Container test-nano-1  Starting                                                                                                0.3s 
Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 0a4d05d2775992400fecb66b060c1143d2204935b41702c198d580e7f56d409b: The request 
is not supported.
```

Alternatively, if I run a new container from the command line things seem to work.

```
docker run -it --rm -v test-data:C:/test-data mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809 cmd
```

In the first container I can create a file:

[image: First Container]

In the second container I can see the file:

[image: Second Container]

### Update

The issue appears to be known and documented [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9577). Using lowercase seems to correct the behavior.